# some effects of mdui disappear while using $().html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I'm using mdui(mdui.org), and there's a function of panel.

when I put the codes in the html body, everything is fine.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kKer.png)

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqdhb.png)

which means i can open and close the panel by clicking the arrow;

however, because there are some parameters required to modify the html/css, I use $(selector).html(code) to add some html inside: a table element with id "table"

the script code is:

```
<script>

    var randomScalingFactor = function () {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    };

    var html = '<thead>\n' +
        '                <tr>\n' +
        '                    <th>Name</th>\n' +
        '                    <th>Buy</th>\n' +
        '                    <th>Sell</th>\n' +
        '                </tr>\n' +
        '                </thead>\n' +
        '                <tbody class="mdui-panel" mdui-panel>';

    var receivedInfo = [{
            "id": 001,
            "cur_price": 10,
            "all_prices": [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()],
            "company_name": "test1",
            "total": 500,
            "dividend": 20,
            "hand_up": 0,
            "sell_remain": 5,
            "buy_remain": 10
        }, {
            "id": 002,
            "cur_price": 100,
            "all_prices": [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()],
            "company_name": "test2",
            "total": 5000,
            "dividend": 200,
            "hand_up": 00,
            "sell_remain": 50,
            "buy_remain": 100
        }]
    ;


       function createDom() {
                $.each(receivedInfo, function() {
                html += '<tr> <td class="mdui-panel" mdui-panel> <div class="mdui-panel-item"> <div class="mdui-panel-item-header"> <div class="mdui-panel-item-title">';
                html += this.company_name + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="mdui-panel-item-summary">Current Price: ' + this.cur_price + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="mdui-panel-item-summary">Now you have: ' + this.hand_up + '</div>';
                html += '<i class="mdui-panel-item-arrow mdui-icon material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i> </div> <div class="mdui-panel-item-body">';
                html += '<p>total: ' + this.total + '</p>';
                html += '<p>dividend: ' + this.dividend + '</p>';
                html += '<p>sell remain: ' + this.sell_remain + '</p>';
                html += '<p>buy remain: ' + this.buy_remain + '</p>';
                html += '</div> </div> </td> <td> <form>';
                html += '<input type="hidden" name=' + this.id + '>';
                html += '<div class="mdui-textfield"> <input class="mdui-textfield-input" type="text" name="amount"> </div> <button type="submit" class="mdui-btn mdui-btn-raised mdui-ripple mdui-color-theme-accent">Buy </button> </form> </td>';
                html += '<td> <form>';
                html += '<input type="hidden" name=' + this.id + '>';
                html += '<div class="mdui-textfield"> <input class="mdui-textfield-input" type="text" name="amount"> </div> <button type="submit" class="mdui-btn mdui-btn-raised mdui-ripple mdui-color-theme-accent">Sell </button> </form> </td> </tr>';
                })
                html += '</tbody>';
    };


    $(document).ready(function () {

        createDom();
        $('#table').html(html);
    });
</script>
```

but the result is that, when I click the arrow, the panel cannot be opened :( 
is there any solution? to be honest idk how MDUI let the panel open when the arrow is clicked

Comment: Odds are you have an event handler set to listen to specific clicks on specific elements, and when you use `.html()` it removes those elements and puts new ones in that do not have handlers set.  I would suggest you change the click handler to use event delegation rather than direct handler binding, [more info](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

when you use `$('#table').html(html);`, the Panel instance in the table will be destroyed, you need reinitialize it.

if you use `mdui-panel` attributes and MDUI version >= 0.4.0, just call `mdui.mutation()` after this line `$('#table').html(html);`